# How to prove define integrate from f(sin x)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

i need help for prove this problem , i dont have idea for this prove, i very appreciate your sugerences.

$$ \int ^{\pi }_{0}xf(\sin x)\,dx = \int ^{\pi }_{0}\frac{\pi }{2} f(\sin x)\,dx $$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $I = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi}xf(\sin x)\,dx$. Substitute $x' = \pi - x$ to get

$I = -\displaystyle\int_{\pi}^{0}(\pi-x')f(\sin (\pi - x'))\,dx' = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi}(\pi-x')f(\sin x')\,dx'$.

So, $2I = I+I = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi}xf(\sin x)\,dx + \int_{0}^{\pi}(\pi-x)f(\sin x)\,dx$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you  :) i very appreciate.